# Java code how to append a color to a list a certain number of times

Tags: java, arrays, colors

How would I code a method (named extendSequence) that appends a color to a list a certain number of times. It accepts three parameters in the following order:
A list of colors of type ArrayList
A color to add of type Color
A run-length, or the number of times to append the color, of type int

For example: suppose a list contains Color.Red and Color.Blue. Then the method extendSequence(list, Color.Blue, 2) changes the list so that it has the elements [Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Blue].

Comment: I'd use a `for` loop (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: I would deviate from the instructions and *start* with `public static <T> void extendSequence(List<T> list, T item, int count)`

Comment: Could also use `Arrays.fill`, `Arrays.asList(...)` and `Collection.addAll` if you were intent on not using loops.

Comment: @user2478398 `Stream.generate(...).limit(n).forEach(list::add);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

enum Color{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Color> list=new ArrayList<Color>();
        list.add(Color.Red);
        list.add(Color.Green);
        System.out.println(list);
        extendSequence(list, Color.Blue, 2);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    public static void extendSequence(List<Color> list, Color color, int times){
        if(list!=null) {
            for(int i=1;i<=times;i++)
                list.add(color);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Red, Green]
[Red, Green, Blue, Blue]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<Color> colours = new ArrayList<Color>();
         colours = extendedSequence(colours, Color.blue, 10);
         System.out.println(colours);


    }

    public List<Color> extendedSequence(List<Color> colours, Color addColor, int numberOfTimes ){

while (numberOfTimes != 0) {
            colours.add(addColor);
            numberOfTimes --;
        }

        return colours;

    }
```

Comment: Why do you bother re-assigning the variable on line 2?

Comment: When attempting to use this code, the output I received is the Color objects directly. How would I get their individual red, green, and blue components and print those instead.

Comment: Iterate the list using a for loop, for each Color use the Color.toString()...System.out.println(Color.toString)